# Fluid sub sub menu that's wider than parent li | wp_nav_menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, fluid

With the use of wp_nav_menu Wordpress creates a nice navigation that's easy to maintain. At the moment the navigation has a submenu and a subsubmenu. When you hover over Link 2 a big submenu will open with 5 sub menus and the subsubmenus below it (this way you see what's under the menus).

JSFiddle Example with original menu
http://jsfiddle.net/tSLqV/1/

Normally the .sub-menu will be postion:absolute because it has to hang over some elements. But for some reason jsfiddle doesn't show the .sub.menu properly this way. So in the example it is position:relative now.

=====

JSFiddle Example where I got it working for a part
http://jsfiddle.net/HYBA7/5/

=====

What's the problem?
Well I can display the sub menus including the sub-sub-menus, but I want it to be fluid. If a subsubmenu doesn't fit, it will fall under the other subsubmenus with a float:left; The submenu will then adjust in height.

Normally I would do this:
max-width: 940px;
width: 100%;

Problem is that this ul is nested. When I use 100% it will show all elements at 25% because of the li parent. Not sure why it's working with the second JSFiddle...

Then I thought about giving the ul a width of 400% (4 x 25% makes 100%) But this doesn't work either.

=====

After spending 2 days with this ul li ul li ul li mess I was looking for a different approach. What if i could get rid of all those ul li? And have a div instead (not sure if this is a good way). And then the div won't have that problem with the width of the parent?
Looking in the Wordpress Codex I found it's possible to remove the first ul and change some classes but that's about it.

I'm not sure about part 4.7 by adding conditional classes to menu items, because it still have the ul li and the width will be dependent on what the parent ul li has.

I have read about the Walkers, but I didn't managed to let the ul.sub-menu transform in a div element.

=====

I know it's possible to load an extra menu with just those 5 submenus with the subsubmenus and let it slide in with jQuery, but I like to use it without the help of javascript and make it css only.

Anybody can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, i've managed to make the submenu fluid.

I've found an Walker that adds a class (level-0, level-1) for each submenu.

```
 class UL_Class_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"level-".$depth."\">\n";
  }      
}
```

Then I worked again on the 400% idea. The only thing that was need was the left property needs a value in % as well. So I made this -100% (because there are 4 parent menu items – and it needs to be aligned over the complete menu )

```
li#menu-item-23 ul.level-0 {
position: absolute;
display: none;
/*width: 940px;*/
max-width: 960px;
width: 400%;
left: -100%;
background: #fff;
z-index: 100;
```

}

Will test it later in IE, but Firefox and Safari display everything properly.